# Boot options screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, bootloader, bios

Is it possible to create something more sleek? So like all you see is two boxes, one with the Ubuntu logo and one with the Windows logo?

Any software for this or anything? Would it be something about the BIOS or what?

[image: Boot options]

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a relatively easy way is to use BURG, based on GRUB 2 but that's more of a [superuser](https://superuser.com/) answer. 
If you actually want to delve into writing your own bootloader you should take a look at the [grub](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-download.html) and [burg](http://code.google.com/p/burg/source/checkout) sources

Comment: I believe BRUG is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Write own bootloader. See Grub source code or ReactOS Free loader.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: This isn't a very feasible option for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the version of grub you have, you might be able to use [themes](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Theme-file-format.html).

It is an experimental feature but it should be able to do what you want.

You will have to do quite a bit of googling though.

good luck :)

EDIT:
If you just want to reduce the number of choices, that is fairly simple.

But again that depends on the version of grub you have.

you just need  to make some changes to configuration files